# HTTP Basic Authentication in Spring Web Services Integration Tests

Tags: spring, soap, integration-testing, basic-authentication, spring-ws

I have a SOAP web service written in Spring Web Services that I would like to integration test.

I would like to use `spring-ws-test` as the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/reference/#_writing_server_side_integration_tests) points to. So, the test code is similar to the example in the reference, something like that:

```java
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;                                      

  private MockWebServiceClient mockClient;

  @Before
  public void createClient() {
    mockClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);               
  }

  @Test
  public void customerEndpoint() throws Exception {
    Source requestEnvelope = new ResourceSource(new ClassPathResource("request.xml"));
    Source responsePayload = new ResourceSource(new ClassPathResource("response.xml"));

    mockClient.sendRequest(withSoapEnvelope(requestPayload)).                              
      andExpect(payload(responsePayload));                                            
  }
```

However, the endpoint I am testing is using basic authentication and it expects to read values in the `Authorization` header. It is not using `spring-security` for that task but it has custom logic that gets the HTTP headers by getting the `HttpServletResponse` from the [`TransportContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/transport/context/TransportContextHolder.html#getTransportContext()). So, the request triggers the endpoint but it fails to retrieve the basic authentication `base64` token.

The question is, how may I pass HTTP headers in that situation? Is it possible at all? If not what is the preferred alternative?

I have read the `javadoc` and I cannot find a way to pass the headers. Also, I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502543/add-basic-http-authentication-to-mockwebserviceclient/45561818) which is similar but it doesn't help me much.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have control over the endpoint under test and/or it is legacy. Is that correct?

Comment: You assume correct. It is not legacy but it is not under my control. I don't know if I am wrong but I have concluded that it is not possible because `spring-ws-test` doesn't use the default `DispatcherSevlet` and the `HttpServletResponse` is not populated at all. I have tried to write my tests with `rest-assured` and it seems to work OK (I followed this: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/28360/using-rest-assured-library-for-testing-soap-webservices). I don't like that I cannot pass an xml file to check the response as I could with `spring-ws-test` but it seems to work fine in general.